# Vue.js Set Radio Buttons Checked Only If Binded Input Type is Radio Button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like for all the input types I have that are radio buttons to be checked, but for all the other input types not. I use v-bind to pass the input type and I do pass the checked value in a similar value, which works, but it also interacts with other input types in an undesired way, e.g. for my input number, it shows the value you choose to enter to the right, in spite of having set their checked value to false. This is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cgrwe0u8/6/

```
new Vue({
  el: '#quizz',
  data: {
    questions:[
        {question: 'What is your gender?', answer: '', type: 'radio', checked: 'true'},
        {question:'How old are you?', answer: '', type: 'number', checked: 'false'},
      {question:'How many times do you workout per week?', answer: '', type: 'number', checked: 'false'},
    ],
    index:0
  },
  computed:{
    currentQuestion(){
        return this.questions[this.index]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    next(){
        if(this.index + 1 == this.questions.length)
        this.index = 0;
      else
        this.index++;

    },
    previous(){

        if(this.index - 1 < 0)
        this.index = this.questions.length - 1;
      else
        this.index--;
    }

  }
})
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="quizz" class="question">
    <h2>
      {{ currentQuestion.question }}
    </h2>
    <input v-bind:type="currentQuestion.type" v-model="currentQuestion.answer" :checked="currentQuestion.checked">
    {{ currentQuestion.answer }}
<div class='button' id='next'><a href='#' @click="next">Next</a></div>
<div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#' @click="previous">Prev</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is why it displays the answer, then that's the expected behavior, because currentQuestion.answer is bind to the input by the v-model.
So if u don't want the currentQuestion.answer to be shown just delete this line.

> {{ currentQuestion.answer}}

Comment: Well that works, but the reason currentQuestion.answer is bound is cos I'll need all the inserted answers from all the questions for the result at the end of the survey. If they are not bound, how will I be able to obtain all the answers from the input to later be able to process them and output a result based on the answers?

Comment: the answers are already stored, at the end of the survey you can loop through "questions" and read answer property.

Comment: Thanks! Well the reason I used bind is because I will need to validate an answer from a specific question from the questions array and depending on the input value show specific question, if not skip that question and proceed to the following. e.g. q4 if and only if user enters 40 as answer, show q5 if not skip to q6. I guess I'll still be able to do this using a component.

Comment: You're welcome, and yes I guess you can do that using your approach.